# Should questions at some point be closed as moot or obsolete?

Tags: discussion

Without any disrespect to [Trish](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/10334/trish) who answered this question today, after the fact, based upon what actually happened, at some point, should questions like the following question from 2016:

[North Korea's participation in Tokyo 2020 Summer olympics](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13687/north-koreas-participation-in-tokyo-2020-summer-olympics)

be closed because they are obsolete or moot?

Answer (score 2):

### Closure might not be required

I just came to the question as I was looking for other [north-korea](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-korea) questions, so the tag would be preserved and not die, and realized that the situation did solve itself. Since the question might have historical note, it should be retained.

While the situation itself became moot, it was not from the beginning - and someone might know how the originally planned DPRK participants were planning to make their way to Japan. An answer that incorporates that (plus the fact that it did not play out that way) would make a better answer, so I would prefer the question to stay open.